# disk requirements for 15.04

Tags: 15.04, ssd, swap, disk

How much space does Ubuntu 15.04 (64 bit) use on a SSD disk?

How much swap space to assign for standard desktop usage?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a swap file or swap partition on the SSD/HDD](http://askubuntu.com/questions/332524/creating-a-swap-file-or-swap-partition-on-the-ssd-hdd) Ubuntu 15.04 uses a *minumum* of 5 GB of disk space, however that information is not very useful to you because you'll surely use more disk space than that.

Answer (score 3):

When you have enough RAM, like 16Gb, and not doing memory intensive tasks, like professional design, you don't need any swap at all. It will be even detrimental to have it, because Linux can't resist the urge to swap something even if it is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Generally the space used on a SSD is the same as on a commonly used HDD.
The amount depends on what you want to store within the operating system.

Regarding lifetime span of SSD it is recommended to store personal data on a HDD.
The amount of swap you should consider depends on the amount of RAM you have.

See this guide for more information -> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq

Answer (score 0):

usually, a clean ubuntu installation takes MAX 10GB of space. Regarding the Swap space, you should dedicate the double of your RAM

Answer (score 0):

Swap in Linux works exactly like virtual memory in Windows, providing hard drive space in case our RAM fills up.

Swap space in Linux is used when the amount of physical memory (RAM) is full. If the system needs more memory resources and the RAM is full, inactive pages in memory are moved to the swap space.

Swap should equal **2x physical RAM for up to 2 GB** of physical RAM, and then an additional 1x physical RAM for any amount above 2 GB, but never less than 32 MB.

Recommended swap space: 4 GB

(That's formula which usually used but in practice you do not need to allocated a Swap Space when you have RAM **more than 5 GB** unless you run a busy server).

For SSD:minimum is 8 GB. It is recommended to make it at **least 15 GB**.
 Warning: your system will be blocked if the root partition is full.

For more details [help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace#Swap](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace#Swap_.28very_recommended.29)